# Visual Studio 2017 Graphics Debugger - No such interface supported

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, graphics

So i have a new set up of windows 10 Home Edition on my PC and installed VS 2017 Community Edition. When i build and run the app it runes absolutely fine. But if i use the graphics debugger i get the app open and i print screen to snapshot a frame. The window opens and it shows the following

[image]

If i choose to open that frame then i get the following error - An error occurred. Playback of your application may be incomplete(HRESULT = 0x80004002) "No such interface supported"
[image]

Does anyone have any ideas what this could be as it worked fine on my laptop and for the record. Opening a brand new Directx12 app project with the spinning cube also does this.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look for the question at [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/417292/visual-studio-directx-graphics-debugging-tool-can.html). I suppose you are using Windows version 1809 or higher.
Graphics Debugging Tool does no longer support DirectX12 after 1809. Instead, you should use the [PIX for Windows](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pix/download/) in future.